# j2me code for blackberry application to display battery level

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How can I make a Blackberry application display the battery level using J2ME?

Comment: It's monday, okay...
But don't let the laziness get you, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944247/get-battery-status-from-j2me
Also try some popular web search engines. Come on ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you're developing a native cldc blackberry app i'd rather use

`net.rim.device.api.system.DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel();`

if you're developing MIDlet the only chance is to use the mobile sensor api.

Answer (score 0):

You also can have it display in the titlebar if you are making an app for newer devices

```
StandardTitleBar TitleBar = new StandardTitleBar()
        //.addIcon("my_logo.png")
        .addTitle("App title")
        .addNotifications()
        .addNotifications()
        .addSignalIndicator();
        TitleBar.setPropertyValue(StandardTitleBar.PROPERTY_BATTERY_VISIBILITY,
                StandardTitleBar.BATTERY_VISIBLE_ALWAYS);
        setTitleBar(TitleBar);
```

PS, its also very nice for you to mark something as answered.